# Similar account names in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I asked for help. 
I have a database table in which the accounts. There are columns such as id, name, etc. I need to find records with a similar name, to check for duplicates. Account names that I need to check, for example, can be a.s. .: ABF a.s, ABF, a.s., "ABCD s.r.o", ABCD s.r.o, REWAQ a.s, REWAQ v.o.s. Different can be: , or "" or ending(ABC s.r.o. / ABC v.o.s).
The table has about 150,000 entries. It's possible to make a query that returns me a similar account names and I can check duplicity?
I created this question, but I subquery returns more than one value.

[image]

I will be very glad for any advice.
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Have you try a simple `count` with a `group by` ? adding a `having` to remove the unique rows would be good too. PS : The duplicate condition are not really clear

Comment: Precisely define what is "similar".  Once you have managed to precisely define what is similar, you will know how easy it is to do this.  (Spoiler: you won't. And it isn't.)

Comment: yes I tried, but count will return the number and I need to return full names  of similar account

Comment: So add the name in the `select` ... since it is the clause of the `group by`, this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work for you :

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) count FROM accounts GROUP BY name Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: This is my guess too but this lack the possibility to add a condition for a `similar` account

Comment: Yes, it will be works. But for account, which have same name. My problem is, that there are accounts, which have similar names,f.e.: 
"ABCD s.r.o" 
and
ABCD s.r.o,
And these accounts I need to check too.

Comment: different is `,` in both string ??

Comment: different can be: , or "" or ending(ABC s.r.o. / ABC v.o.s)